# How to use GNU Root Debian from android terminal emulator?

Tags: shell, terminal

I install GNU Root Debian on my android. Also i install jdk8. I can compile java programs. For example i can get java version.

```
cd /data/data/com.gnuroot.debian/debian/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181/bin
./java -version
```

But it works only in GNU Root Debian terminal emulator. How i can use java from android terminal emulator? I got error: cannot execute binary file.

Android shell cannot run java? How i can change shell to debian shell?

Answer (score 0):

GNURoot Debian run script in /data/data/com.gnuroot.debian/support/launchProot when app started. In termux I run it script and java works!